# Do Google Service Account with chat.bot scope work for all Google WorkSpaces?

Tags: google-api, google-chat

We are developing a Google Chat App and in particular scenario we need to post a Async card message with interactive components to the User.

We followed https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/v1/messages/create and https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth/service-accounts and a service account with the scope *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot*.

We can able to post the Async card message using the Service Account for our workspace domain say for example *myappdomain.com*.

We saw in Google documents that the Service Accounts are not bound to a Domain.

Can we use the same Service Account Credentials to post the Async Card message to a user who is in another workspace say *externaldomain.com* ?

If not, do need to ask the Admin of *externaldomain.com* to create a Service Account with the needed scope and share the .json file to us ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use the same Service Account Credentials to post the Async Card message to a user who is in another workspace say externaldomain.com ?

If your application is published as a public app ([learn more](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/apps-publish?authuser=1)), and it's installed by externaldomain.com, you can send an asynchronous Card message to a user who is part of a different workspace, such as externaldomain.com.

> If not do need to ask the Admin of externaldomain.com to create a Service Account with the needed scope and share the .json file to us ?

Google Chat apps with the "chatbot" scope are typically tied to a specific project. If the app is not publicly published, it's limited to use within the organization's workspace. Even if you utilize a Service Account from a different organization, sending chats to another organization is not possible.

My suggestion is to strongly consider [publish your chat app](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/apps-publish?authuser=1) to do that. Otherwise, you may find it necessary to create a separate app for each workspace organization.

Comment: Thanks @muhammad-dyas-yaskur. Is there any way to test the app for different domains without publishing ? We enabled the Google Chat API with OAuth2.0 Client Id and Service Accounts Credentials. Our OAuth2.0 Client Id is type External. if we add the users in externaldomain.com as test users can we test the Async Card message post with our Service Credentials ?

Comment: No, it's impossible for now. You only create  card message with chatbot(service account), and Service Accounts Credentials is not related to OAuth2.0.